# RAVE Report Error "dbrtl160.bpl missing"

Tags: delphi

When I run RAVE Reports Designer from an IDE (Delphi XE2) I get this error:

"The program can not start because dbrtl160.bpl missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem"

However, in the Delphi XE2 folder the file `dbrtl160.bpl` exists.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: I assumed this is with update4 applied ?

Comment: Maybe missing registry entry for dbrtl160.bpl?

Answer (score 1):

The file needs to be either in the same folder as your application, or a folder on the system `PATH`. The IDE uses it from it's own folder, but when your app (or in this case, RAVE) runs it's not in the IDE folder. The IDE usually adds the necessary RAVE folder to the `PATH` during installation, but if you've installed a RAVE update it could have been deleted or changed, or something else you've installed damaged thte PATH statement.

Delphi packages are just special DLLs, and they're loaded by LoadLibrary when your app starts. The rules for finding them are those that LoadLibrary uses, as well. The search order is specified in the Remarks section of the [LoadLibrary documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Rave component not appear in IDE Palette.

Comment: 1. Check 'Component->Install Packages' - is RAVE's package there? Is it's checkbox checked? If it's not there, reinstall RAVE (run installer, choose Modify, install RAVE). If it's there but not checked, check it. :-)

Comment: Yes, I check. And saw checked design time package. But it is not appear in IDE. http://prasid.in/screencap/1344438526-oKxMrt.png

Comment: Hmmm. Mine starts fine, when I run it from `Tools->Rave Reports Designer` in the IDE menu. I think you need to do the repair install I mentioned before (re-run the XE2 installer, choose `Modify`, and add RAVE to your installation. It will install it again and properly set up the IDE and PATH for you.

Comment: Now Palette appear on IDE but same error when run rave.exe from IDE. See: http://prasid.in/screencap/1344440951-6plNLH.png

Comment: My final guess: See if you have an environmental variable named `PLATFORM` defined on your system. (Open a command prompt, and type `SET PLATFORM` and hit enter. If you see anything but "Environment variable PLATFORM not found", you do.) If you do, remove it by using the Control Panel system properties window. The IDE sets that when you set a target platform, and a pre-defined one (usually done by the computer maker) conflicts with it and causes file location problems for the IDE. If that doesn't help, you really need to contact Embarcadero Support; this is a vendor support question.

Comment: Your idea parially working. I saw component in IDE and easy drag and work but I need to Run rave.exe externally. From IDE "Rave Report Designer" not work. Ner error received "vclimg160.bpl" missing.

Answer (score 0):

if you using x64 windows, you must copy rave files to C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\Rave...